# Filter on ComboBox Selected Item as String

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, tostring

I am attempting to use a `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to filter on a `DataGrid`, however I am having an issue accessing the `SelectedItem` as a `string`. This is what I have attempted so far;

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem cItem in departmentComboBox.ItemsSource)
{
    if (departmentComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<EmployeeModel>(x => x.Department == departmentComboBox.SelectedItem as string));
        break;
    }
}
```

This results in an exception;

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.
```

`x.Department` is of type `string`. How can I access the `SelectedItem` correctly so that I can use it in my filtering method correctly?

EDIT: To show how the ComboBox items are added;

```
List<string> distinctList = Employees.Select(i => i.Department).Distinct().ToList();
distinctList.Insert(0, "Everyone");
distinctList.Sort();
departmentComboBox.ItemsSource = distinctList;
```

Comment: You can use SelectedValue if it is really string. But if it`s actually your class then eather use explicit convertion and call needed field (YourDepartmentClass)departmentComboBox.SelectedItem.Name for example,
eather override YourDepartmentClass.ToString method and use departmentComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString (overwriting to String is a bad option )

Comment: How are you setting departmentComboBox.ItemSource? ItemSource is used to generate the ComboBoxItems, you cant use it to access  the ComboBoxItems themselves

Comment: @Cbreeze thanks, I've added an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this way:

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem cItem in departmentComboBox.ItemsSource){
if (departmentComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    string selectedItemName = this.departmentComboBox.GetItemText(this.departmentComboBox.SelectedItem);
    criteria.Add(new Predicate<EmployeeModel>(x => x.Department.Equals(selectedItemName)));
    break;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ToString()` method of the `SelectedItem`.

```cs
foreach (ComboBoxItem cItem in departmentComboBox.ItemsSource)
{
    if (departmentComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<EmployeeModel>(x => x.Department == departmentComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        break;
    }
}
```

Ensure, that there is no `null` value in the items of the combobox, otherwise you can use the following code:

```cs
foreach (ComboBoxItem cItem in departmentComboBox.ItemsSource)
{
    if (departmentComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        criteria.Add(new Predicate<EmployeeModel>(x => x.Department == "" + departmentComboBox.SelectedItem));
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of string to populate the combo box, via item source, which is great, the confusion is over how to access them. Using ItemSource again will give you back the same list of string, which you are then trying to check to see if each is the same as the selected. A better way of getting the selected item is through the .SelectedItem property. Check for Null first and you can ditch the for loop too :)

```
        if (departmentComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<EmployeeModel>(x => x.Department == departmentComboBox.SelectedItem as string));
        }
```